# Can RenderDoc debug linux binaries?

Tags: debugging

I have downloaded RenderDoc for linux, but when passing a program as an argument it says "wrong file format", i have tried renaming to program.bin but same error.
Is it a RenderDoc linux binary to debug only Windows app ?

Comment: If you are saying, you are using the command line for calling RenderDoc, you should include the full command that you used for starting RenderDoc. And keep in mind: RenderDoc is intended for debugging your own programs only.

Comment: Yes i'm lauching it from the console with the program I want to debug as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderDoc mainly supports debugging Windows apps; Linux compatibility is limited and experimental. Use alternatives like GDB or Valgrind instead.